# Bootstarp 4 Modal Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Имеется такой код модального окна:

```html
<div class="cataloge-modal modal fade" id="catalogeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-replace="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2 class="text-uppercase">Заголовок</h2>
              
              <div class="bd-example">
                <div class="bd-example">
                  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="img/Filter/914673_v01_b.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                       
                      </div>
                      
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                Закрыть</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Далее создаю 2 окно на bootstrap 4, во 2 я поменял id и содержимое:

```html
<div class="cataloge-modal modal fade" id="catalogeModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-replace="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h2 class="text-uppercase">Заголовок</h2>
              
              <div class="bd-example">
                <div class="bd-example">
                  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="img/Filter/914673_v01_b.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                       
                      </div>
                      
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                Закрыть</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Далее создаю кнопки, которые запускают все это дело:

```html
<a  class="cataloge-link"  data-toggle="modal"href="#catalogeModal">
<a  class="cataloge-link"  data-toggle="modal" href="#catalogeModal2">
```

В итоге 1 окно запускается, от 2 только анимация запуска, а окна нет. Если я уберу 1, то 2 запустится или же наоборот.

---

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В представленном вами коде, у каждого из окон не хватает по паре закрывающих тегов `div`:

```html
<div id="catalogeModal" ...>
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Разметка первого окна -->

  </div><!-- Добавить здесь -->
</div><!-- Добавить тут -->

<div id="catalogeModal2" ...>
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Разметка второго окна -->

  </div><!-- Добавить здесь -->
</div><!-- Добавить тут -->
```

---

**PS** На текущем сайте при вставке кода в снипет, используйте кнопку <kbd>Привести в порядок</kbd> слева в панели.

Answer (score 0):

Все я решил вопрос проблема была в подгрузке файлов который гугл не соизволил мне описать.